# Some atlas artifacts when using atlas on Mac

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine

My game background accidentally got some artifacts when I added sprites to atlas.

Sorry for quality, there is no better around right now.
But you can see the problem anyway.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answering right away, as it may help somebody.

It happened to me when I was using Max Texture Size = 4096, if I set 2048 - it shows no artifacts.